# CSS builder for tabs

Tags: css, menu, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

I am looking for a tool to help me generate stylesheets for standard interfaces, like tabs. Something like the jQuery UI theme builder, but lighter.

Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: What's wrong with theme roller? What about it is too heavy for you?

Comment: Here is an example of class for a jQuery UI tab: "ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active ui-state-hover".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://www.freelayouts.com/websites/html-templates) website contains hundreds of HTML and CSS templates which are free, and many have tabs implemented.  You'll have to add the JQuery yourself to make the tabs dynamic, otherwise they work normally as static links.